# GWT JsInterop native class issue

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I am having a JsInterop issue, while wrapping up some javascript code.

the JavaScript is something like

```
com = { gwidgets: {} };
com.gwidgets.Spring = function () {
        this.name = "hello";    
};

com.gwidgets.Spring.prototype.getName = function () {return "test";
};
```

The JsInterop class is:

```
package com.gwidgets.leaflet;

import jsinterop.annotations.JsMethod;
import jsinterop.annotations.JsType;

@JsType(isNative=true)
public class Spring {

    @JsMethod
    public native String getName();
}
```

However, when I instantiate the class and try to call the `getName()` method, I get an error:

> leafletwrapper-0.js:1183 Uncaught TypeError: spring.getName is not a
>   function

Any ideas what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to javascript you have, one solution could be to add namespace to annotation

```
import jsinterop.annotations.JsMethod;
import jsinterop.annotations.JsType;

@JsType(isNative=true, namespace = "com.gwidgets")
public class Spring {

    @JsMethod
    public native String getName();
}
```

Or move java class Spring to package com.gwidgets (same as javascript)

Or change namespace of javascript to match package in class Spring

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works now. I removed namespaces and used namespace=JsPackage.Global                                                                             I also used GWT 2.8 VC-Snapshot instead of 2.8 beta which seems to cause a problem for JSinterop

Comment: keeping namespace is better than use just global, if your code is to coexist with another javascript library. Someone else can use Spring and rewrite your references if loaded later. (I understand that this method is just test)